# JIRA, add a Workflow to a Workflow Scheme?

Tags: jira

In JIRA, what is the appropriate procedure to add a Workflow to a Workflow Scheme?

In my case I created a new Issue Type which is referenced by a newly created Workflow. In order to add the Workflow to a Workflow Scheme, the Workflow Scheme must be Inactive. In order for the Workflow Scheme to be Inactive, I have change each Project's Workflow Scheme to something else. Only when there are no Projects using the Workflow Scheme can I edit it.

When changing a Project to a different Workflow Scheme ("Associate Workflow Scheme to Project"), JIRA warns that a backup should be made and that every single issue will be changed. Something tells me this is an overkill for such a simple change. I really don't want to alter every issue just to add a new Workflow to a Workflow Scheme.

Am I missing something?

**Follow up:** [According to Atlassian](http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?threadID=35012), there's no choice but to migrate to the new Workflow Scheme.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to Admin, Schemes, Workflow Schemes. Copy the Workflow scheme currently in use by your project. Edit the copy and assign the new workflow to the issue type. Then go back to the project and select the new workflow scheme, which may prompt you about migration of issues if necessary.

It's not overkill, it's just being careful. You don't actually change anything unless you have to, for example if there are issues of the new issue type in the project.

~Matt